# How can I replace all with a variable?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was making a filter for my Discord.js bot. If the character is not in the English alphabet, it should be removed so the filter can check if a word in the string is filtered.

```
const alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "j", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

bot.on("message", message => {
if (message.author.bot) return;
if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;

var args = message.content;
var argsnt = message.content.toLowerCase().toString().split("");
var str = "";

// Checking each character.

  argsnt.forEach(element => {
  if (!alphabet.includes(element) && !str.includes(element)) {
    str = str + element;
    console.log("add");
    console.log(str);
  }
});

// Removing the characters.

const search = str;
const replacer = new RegExp(search, 'g');
args = args.replace(replacer, "");

message.reply(args);

});
```

Issues:

If you have two different symbols, it will only remove one of the symbols.

If it is something that opens or closes like parenthesis it will give me an error about the regular expression.

Note:

The only error I have received from the code above is the regular expression error. I have researched and tested many things for over a week now and haven't found any solutions. I'm not trying to make the fastest method right now. I am only trying to find something that works.

Comment: can you show some examples?

Comment: One symbol: Tes!t > Test

Two symbols: T!es@t > T!es@t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would actually do this with a RegEx `.replace()`, like this:

```js
args.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')
```

If you use this, make sure args remains as the message content, not the split message content.